# Loading Require.js Optimized File

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using require.js successfully with many separate files:

```
require(['app/login/Login'], function (app) {
   new app.Login();
});
```

This all works exactly as expected, with each module loading as required.

I've now run my code through the [Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) and have one combined .js file "everything.js" - which is just what I want.

But how do I actually load this?

```
require(['everything'], function (app) {
   new app.Login();
});
```

Returns me undefined for `app`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is in the [optimizer docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs):

> If you want to include require.js with the main.js source, you can use
>   this kind of command:
>
> node ../../r.js -o baseUrl=. paths.requireLib=../../require name=main include=requireLib out=main-built.js
>
> Since "require" is a reserved dependency name, you
>   create a "requireLib" dependency and map it to the require.js file.
>   Once that optimization is done, you can change the script tag to
>   reference "main-built.js" instead of "require.js", and your optimized
>   project will only need to make one script request.

i.e. you can change the **script tag** to reference "main-built.js" **instead** of "require.js"